# changing $scope doesn't apply to view

Tags: angularjs

I have my `controller` as:

```
app.controller('myPapersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.papers = [];

    $scope.refreshGrid = function(){
        $http.get('api/getPapers').success(function (d) {
            $scope.papers = d;
        })
    }

    $scope.register = function () {
        $.post('api/register', $('#newPaperForm').serializeArray(), function (d, s, j) {
            $scope.refreshGrid()
        }
    }
}
```

and in view I have a button like this (some Jade):

```
button(ng-click="register()") Regsiter
```

and an element with `ng-repeat` like this:

```
li(ng-repeat="paper in papers") {{paper.blah}}
```

when i click on the register button I expect to post my data on the server, it happens, but I also expect that my `ng-repeat` element repeat! but it doesn't!

I have traced the code, `refreshGrid()` runs and changes the `$scope` but nothing happens in real. why?

Comment: Check if your get request returns data?

Comment: Why do you use jQuery and not AngularJS to post? Why do you access the DOM from a controller, instead of using the model?

Comment: you are *replacing* `$scope.papers` in the api call, which destroys the two way binding.  You should be pushing / splicing the array instead.

Comment: try `$scope.papers.push(d)`

Comment: @maioman that creates a nested array. There is no problem assigning the scope variable inside the callback as shown

Comment: thanks @Claies, but if I put a button to execute `$scope.refreshGrid()`, it runs and my data is shown!

Comment: @JBNizet does it really matter? AngularJs uses the same way to post and get as JQuery. what can I don instead of accessing DOM? I want to serialize a from, with all inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You should call `$scope.$apply()` in your `refreshGrid()` method after `$scope.papers = d`. This should update your view.

Comment: thanks, but gives me a nice error saying: currently running $digest